# rsync to Windows Server NTFS share always copies all files/folders

Tags: windows, rsync

I am using rsync to backup a folder on my Lubuntu 20.04 host to an NTFS share on a Windows 2022 Server. The command below always copies every file and folder, despite the fact that no changes have been made:

```
rsync -av "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"
```

I've tried the options below, but it made no difference:

```
rsync -av --modify-window=1 "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"

rsync -av --modify-window=2 "/var/www/" "/media/server2022/web"
```

Any ideas for how I can sync only new or modified files/folders?

Comment: Perhaps --checksum does the trick

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried adding --checksum but got the same result - all files/folders were copied again

Comment: I am sorry that i am no help for you. I gues the main problem here are the different filesystems or the way how ntfs handles some metadata. As far as I know rsync compares Modification Time and Size and with the `--checksum` you force rsync to do a checksum instead. Normaly if both files are identical than its checksum is identical too. You could try an md5sum on one file on you ext4 filesystem (Lubuntu) and one md5sum on the same file at the ntfs filesystem and see if it is different.

Comment: What happens if you rsync to an ext4 (or something linux) folder on your computer. Then repeat to a NTFS partition. Would identify what is causing the issue. Also does -vvv add verbosity to the output of this command? I haven’t found anything that says it does but rsync is very sophisticated and things like ssh can increase verbosity

Comment: If I use the same rsync command to sync to an EXT4 it sends all files and folders on the first execution, and only changed files on subsequent executions. So all as expected, EXCEPT...I also get an error message: "rsync: failed to set times on "/media/Samsung2Tb1/.": Operation not permitted (1)" and "rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1207) [sender=3.1.3]"

Comment: That sounds like an ownership issue. Is the user that runs the rsync the owner of all the files and directories involved? That’s not relevant to your original problem https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/rsync-failed-to-set-times-operation-not-permitted.51954/

Comment: The folder is /var/www (and its subfolders), which is owned by root I believe. If I prefix the rsync command with sudo when copying to the EXT4 partition I no longer get the errors, and only new or modified files get copied. If I use sudo to copy to the NTFS partition I get the same problem, however - all files and folders are copied every time

Comment: So NTFS doesn’t understand the same permissions structure that is in use in linux. You’ve tried --checksum. There could still be a permissions difference triggering the unnecessary transfer. Seems there’s a way of making rsync set the default permissions of the receiving file system. It’s in flo’s answers here. https://superuser.com/questions/472362/only-show-changed-files-while-syncing-from-ext4-to-ntfs Might be worth a try. I’m guessing it might take two runs before it works if it works. Others report --size works well with FAT. Perhaps checksum is too exacting

Comment: Thanks. I tried --perms and --chmod=ugo=rwX, but no luck.

Comment: rsync can be complicated. From my reading of it you don’t want --perms but you do want --no-p --no-g --chmod=ugo=rwX  This is outside of my practical experience so good luck.

Comment: I just tried --no-p --no-g --chmod=ugo=rwX. This time I get the opposite problem - it just says "skipping directory" (even when I've added a new file to the source directory).  :0(

Comment: I just tried the -i flag to see if it offered any clues. Each file copy is prefixed with: ".d...pog... " ???